# How to add best seller products for archive pages in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I want to list best seller products of that category under the bottom of the category page.

I am able to add custom code (php) under each category via GeneratePress theme's elements.
I tried few plugins including this one. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-best-selling-products/

But these are not good till now.
I want to have as simple as possible. Name and Price. Something like this;

Best seller **cell phones** (Cell Phones are a category name here)

1. iphone 13 pro max – 1299 USD
2. Samsung galaxys s22 – 999 USD
   3..

Asked about it in wordpress forums. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-best-seller-products-title-and-price/#post-15519512
Tried different plugins

Answer (score 0):

In function.php add this code

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'My product hits WC', '' ),
    'id' => 'category-hits',
    'description' => __( 'Add widget', '' ),
    'before_widget' => '<div class="hits-row">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<div class="wg_title"><span>',
    'after_title' => '</span></div>',
) );
```

after in your template child-theme add new position for widget

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'category-hits' ); ?>
```

For example in file site\wp-content\themes\theme-child\archive-product.php after code

```
/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
```